# How do you search for the term "stack overflow" on stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I want to search for questions related to stack overflows, and of course I'd like to include results on stackoverflow.com. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean using Stack Overflow's search, or using external search engine (e.g. Google)?

Comment: Either way, but primarily through Google. Basically I want to get answers about X and stack overflows, but I end up with a list of results about X on stackoverflow.com. Even the search within the site has this problem to some extent.

Answer (score 5):

Either use the search bar in the upper right corner normally, or search

```
site:stackoverflow.com stack overflow exception
```

On Google.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that hasn't already been mentioned: you can always browse the [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tag.

You might find the occasional question about the Stack Overflow *site* there, but the tag itself is supposed to be used for stack overflow *exceptions*.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a complete list of the Google Search Operators](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html)

[Another list](http://www.satinderspace.com/2012/08/24-google-power-searching-operators.html)

If you want, you can also use something like this in the google search `inurl:*stackoverflow.com stack overflow exception`

With this query, you will also get the result from subdomains, like for example [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://www.careers.stackoverflow.com/)